# How does hot deploy relate with classloading?

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, hotdeploy, dynamic-class-loaders

I am reading good presentation about classloading and `OSGI`.  But I have misunderstanding with  following phrase:

> ```
> • For example:
>
> What app/web servers do for hot deployment
> ```

it is slide #17 from [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/martinlippert/classloading-and-type-visibility-in-osgi-presentation)

screen from slide:

[image]

Please clarify this.

Comment: Looks like the presentation is limiting without footnotes. http://www.liferay.com/web/michael.han/blog/-/blogs/hot-deploy-vs-auto-deploy
I would sugest taking a look at this article.

Answer (score 0):

When you hot-deploy, you are updating a running application. So, if you copy on the server a new .class file, this action by itself would not change the running version previously loaded in memory. You can change an already loaded class in memory only if the target environment gives you a mechanism which dinamically **reload** that class file, that is if it gives you a dynamic classloading.

Comment: Which feature allow to make this. Can you explain without osgi and with osgi difference

Comment: Standard Java does not allow a class to be reloaded by its current class loader. This is something that can be done for debugging (under certain constraints) or by non-standard extensions. Normally to reload a class you need a new classloader which is what OSGi does when you update a bundle.

Comment: @BJ Hargrave Can you help me write hello world with hot deploy code ?

Comment: No. Your request does not make sense.

Comment: @gstackoverflow You can start your study with the following article: http://java.dzone.com/articles/reloading-java-classes-301

Comment: @gstackoverflow perhaps my HoTea project is of interest to you; check out the intro. blog post on http://blog2.vorburger.ch/2015/04/how-to-hot-reload-java-script-like.html, the demo video on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMhY075hx9k, and the src on https://github.com/vorburger/HoTea.